# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use custom icon in flutter, using android studio! I need to know what we want to do in pubspec.yaml. Because I got an error in pubspec.yaml, cant view a icon in our program.

Comment: using any plugin for icon ?

Answer (score 0):

It can help if you specify what sort of icon you are trying to add, and if you share some of your pubspec file. Are we talking about an app icon (using a package like `flutter_launcher_icons`) or icons to use within the app (like the ones created via fluttericon.com).

I'll assume you're talking about launcher icons.

First make sure you have the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

In the root of your `pubspec.yaml` file, you can add lines like:

```yaml
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/myIcon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/myIconForeground.png"
```

This will use `myIcon.png` for the iOS app, and apply the foreground image on a white background for Android (where depending on your phone, a circular or square icon can be used).

Now you may notice the asset paths, you can also add the icons as assets to your app such that you can use them elsewhere.

```yaml
flutter:
  ...
  assets:
    - assets/myIcon.png
    - assets/myIconForeground.png
```

After which you should be able to run the plugin and generate your native icons:

```sh
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```